# Do any regulatory bodies require ISO 9001 QMS certification from airlines or service providers?

Tags: safety

As the aviation industry is transitioning to SMS approach, is having ISO 9001 certification required from any civil aviation authority? Similar to how IATA requires IOSA certification and certain airline /  airport authorities require ISAGO certification for ground handling companies. Note this question is not trying to debate the advantages or disadvantages of ISO 9001 certification towards achieving safety, but rather the presence or non-presence in the regulatory landscape.

Comment: There are quite a few 135 companies in the United States that are transitioning to IS-BAO certification.  There are quite a few European companies that require ISO 9001 certification.  I don't think, however, the push to these standards are done by the regulatory authority but by the insurance companies.

Comment: ISO 9001 for which airline processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no civil aviation authorities that require QMS implementation.

ICAO documentation (Document 9859) discusses the integration of other systems, such as quality and environmental management systems. There are advantages of integrations, such as facilitating data management and reducing redundancies.

For example, a [QMS has many of the same documentation requirements as an SMS](http://aviationsafetyblog.asms-pro.com/blog/how-integrating-qms-and-sms-will-improve-aviation-safety-audit-performance), so an integrated system is logical. However, not all operator benefit from an QMS, especially the smaller ones.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Later on I heard anecdotally a rare case where an airport authority required ISO 9001 certification for ground handling companies, but since the official word from ICAO promotes integration probably means requiring another management system on top of an SMS is unlikely.